# How to await to fetch all voice channels with X people in discord.js V12?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, fetch, discord.js

I am making a Discord bot with discord.js V12. I want to make a command to await to fetch all channels with X people or more, but I am not familiar with awaiting and fetching. Here is my code so far:

Command:

```
    else if (command === 'find') {
        if (!args.length) {
            const findHelp = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Finding')
            .setDescription('Help')
            .addField('Usage', 'Find a free spot on a voice channel & automaticly join for best Among Us experience!')
            .addField('Commands', '`/find <members>` Find a voice channel with minimum of `<members>` people in it.')
            .setColor(0xE92323);
            message.channel.send(findHelp);
        } else if (args.length === 1) {
            const memberMin = args[0];
            const channel = await (fetch(channels.first.members.length(memberMin)))
            message.author.join(channel);
        }
    }
```

I tried without awaiting or fetching but it still doesn't work, while giving an error.

Thanks for taking your time to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your message comes from a guild, you can use the channel cache.

```js
const memberMin = args[0]
const voiceChannels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type == 'voice') // Collection<VoiceChannel>

const yourVoiceChannels = voiceChannels.filter(c => c.members.length >= memberMin) // Collection<VoiceChannel>
```

If you've edited the caching behavior, you'll need to fetch the channels and/or the guild before reading their properties. You can do that with, for example:

```js
const guild = await message.guild.fetch()
```

Comment: I think it will work, but I have another problem - how to send the Message Author to the first fetched channel? I tried `message.member.voice.setChannel(yourVoiceChannels.first());` but It doesn't work and no errors are given.